# How do I run a parameterized SQL query in classic ASP? And is it secure?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, sql-injection

I'm about to have to deal with some SQL code in classic ASP VBScript.

I have two questions.

First, in .net, I'm used to using the System.Data.SqlClient namespace objects to perform queries.  For example:

```
Dim conn as New SqlConnection("Data Source=MyServer;uid=myUid;pwd=myPwd;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;"  
Dim cmd as New SqlCommand("Select fname From myTable where uid=@uid;", conn)  
cmd.Parameters.add(New SqlParameter("@uid",100323)  
conn.open()
Response.Write(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
conn.Close()
```

I've been told that using a parameterized query as such makes my query secure from SQL injection attacks.

I'd like to know what is the equivalent code to do such a query in classic ASP with VBScript and what similar security precautions must be used to guard against SQL injection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are ADODB Objects which do basically the same thing.
ADODB.Command object is the equivalent to SqlCommand.  From there it is basically doing the same as in .NET.

```
set cmd = Server.CreateOject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.CommandText = "select From Table where ID = @id")
set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@id", adInteger, adInput,0,0)
```

I frequently use [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_command.asp) for help about ADO objects.

Comment: This works but is slightly misleading. Being adodb, even thought he parameter is named @id, and the createParameter call is named "@id", I believe it is actually using positioned parameters (as if you were just using ? ? ?).
So if you have multiple values to replace, you MUST call createParameter(...) each time in the appropriate order.