# insert data with classic asp in aspx form

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp-classic

I am using parameterised query for inserting the data in aspx page with classic asp.
Below is my code :

```
cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Sponsor_Inputs 
(sponsor,Spon_Username,Spon_PASSWORD,Spon_First_Name,Spon_Last_Name,Spon_Co_Name,Spon_E_Mail,
  Spon_Phone,Spon_TOU,Remote_Computer_Name,Browser_Type,
  unsub_notif,Spon_CurrentMsg_NL,Spon_Pic_NL,Spon_Web_NL,Spon_Email_NL,
  Spon_YourName_NL,Spon_Phone_NL,Spon_Email,Spon_PhoneBan,Spon_Logo,Spon_YourName,
  Spon_Pic,featurestring,spon_fr_alias,spon_em_addr,spon_sub_line,spon_add_msg,
  spon_add_msg2,Spon_Current_Msg,newsletter_template) 
  values 
     (@sponsor ,@Spon_Username ,@Spon_PASSWORD ,@Spon_First_Name ,@Spon_Last_Name 
      ,@Spon_Co_Name ,@Spon_E_Mail ,@Spon_Phone ,@Spon_TOU ,@Remote_Computer_Name 
      ,@Browser_Type ,@unsub_notif ,@Spon_CurrentMsg_NL ,@Spon_Pic_NL ,@Spon_Web_NL 
      ,@Spon_Email_NL ,@Spon_YourName_NL ,@Spon_Phone_NL ,@Spon_Email ,@Spon_PhoneBan 
      ,@Spon_Logo ,@Spon_YourName ,@Spon_Pic ,@featurestring ,@spon_fr_alias ,@spon_em_addr 
      ,@spon_sub_line ,@spon_add_msg ,@spon_add_msg2 ,@Spon_Current_Msg ,
     @newsletter_template )"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text                               
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@sponsor", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 200, sponsor))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_Username", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 50, Spon_Username))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_PASSWORD", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 50, Spon_PASSWORD))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_First_Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 150, Spon_First_Name))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_Last_Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 150, Spon_Last_Name))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_Co_Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 300, Spon_Co_Name))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_E_Mail", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 150, Spon_E_Mail))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_Phone", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 50, Spon_Phone))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_TOU", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 50, Spon_TOU))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Remote_Computer_Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, , Remote_Computer_Name))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Browser_Type", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, , Browser_Type))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@unsub_notif", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 50, unsub_notif))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_CurrentMsg_NL", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, , Spon_CurrentMsg_NL))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_Pic_NL", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, , Spon_Pic_NL))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_Web_NL", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 250, Spon_Web_NL))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_Email_NL", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 150, Spon_Email_NL))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_YourName_NL", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 300, Spon_YourName_NL))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_Phone_NL", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 50, Spon_Phone_NL))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_Email", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 150, Spon_Email))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_PhoneBan", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 50, Spon_PhoneBan))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_Logo", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, , Spon_Logo))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_YourName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 200, Spon_YourName))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_Pic", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, , Spon_Pic))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@featurestring", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, , featurestring))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@spon_fr_alias", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 200, spon_fr_alias))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@spon_em_addr", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 150, spon_em_addr))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@spon_sub_line", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, , spon_sub_line))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@spon_add_msg", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 50, spon_add_msg))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@spon_add_msg2", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, , spon_add_msg2))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_Current_Msg", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, , Spon_Current_Msg))
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@newsletter_template", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 1, newsletter_template))
rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs = cmd.Execute
```

Using above code i am getting below error :

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated 
in the code.
```

Exception Details:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of 
acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 858:                                        
Line 859:                                    
Line 860:                                          
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@sponsor", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,   
System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 200, sponsor))
Line 861:                                          
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_Username", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,     
System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 50, Spon_Username))
Line 862:                                        
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@Spon_PASSWORD", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 
System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 50, Spon_PASSWORD))
```

What's wrong in it ?
I used the syntax from here : [How do I run a parameterized SQL query in classic ASP? And is it secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579687/how-do-i-run-a-parameterized-sql-query-in-classic-asp-and-is-it-secure)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this code run in the classic asp page, or the asp.net page? `Server.CreateObject` is classic asp, `System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar` is asp.net.

Comment: page is asp.net , coding is asp(vbscript) :). client's requirement.

Comment: i tried to use datatype value from here : http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_comm_createparameter.asp#gsc.tab=0. But, it is also giving error.

Comment: where are you getting the values for `sponsor`,`Spon_Username` etc.. ?

Comment: using this : Request("Spon_First_Name") ... like wise all values.

Comment: when i used adVarChar, adParamInput , it is giving error. so, i think i miss any dll to reference it. which one ? any help.

Comment: Error : "BC30451: 'adVarChar' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Comment: i just replaced "System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar" to System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar. now it will give me another error : Must declare the scalar variable "@sponsor". what i  missing in it ? first quest is , am i going to in right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

Error is definitely caused by the constants you supply for cmd.CommandType and all .NET constants that you use for the parameters. Use constants as per ADO's specifications.

Also experiment with "?" instead of named parameters inside the SQL. It's been some time sonce I last did this, but I seem to remember that I had problems using named parameters in the SQL. This is working code from a solution I maintain:

```
strSQL = ...
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE col1 = 1 AND col2 = 1 AND col3 = ? AND col4 != somevalue "
...
Set objParameter = cmd.CreateParameter("@NamedParamHereIsOk", adInteger, adParamInput, 5) 'Use constants as per "classic" ADO specifications'
objParameter.value = some_value
cmd.Parameters.Append objParameter
```