# Run a MS SQL Query in ASP Classic and Show Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, vbscript

I would like to know how can I run this MS SQL Query in ASP Classic and get the Results as I do in MS SQL.

```
DECLARE @weeks int = 26

;WITH Person AS (
   SELECT
     datediff(ww, DATE_GIVEN, getdate())+1 AS Week,
     AVG(CHECK_AMOUNT) AS Person_Check_Amount
   FROM CHECKS
   WHERE PERSON_NO=11  AND DATE_GIVEN >= dateadd(ww, -@weeks, getdate())
   GROUP BY datediff(ww, DATE_GIVEN, getdate()) +1
)

, Company AS (
    SELECT week,
  AVG (COMPANY_Check_Amount) AS COMPANY_Check_Amount
    FROM (
       SELECT
         datediff(ww, DATE_GIVEN, getdate())+1 AS Week,
         SUM(CHECK_AMOUNT)/COUNT(DISTINCT PERSON_NO) AS COMPANY_Check_Amount
       FROM CHECKS
       WHERE PERSON_NO<>11  AND DATE_GIVEN >= dateadd(ww, -@weeks, getdate())
       GROUP BY datediff(ww, DATE_GIVEN, getdate())+1 
    ) t
  GROUP BY Week
)

SELECT c.week
 , isnull(Person_Check_Amount,0)  Person_Check_Amount
 , isnull(Company_Check_Amount,0) Company_Check_Amount
FROM Person p
FULL OUTER JOIN Company c ON c.week = p.week
ORDER BY Week DESC
```

I would then like to loop this and have the results displayed.

I thought that it was as easy as just this:
dim strQuery = " *PUT ABOVE CODE HERE* " 
and then run: objSchDeductions.Open strQuery
and then: while not objSchDeductions.EOF and just loop all of it until there is no more but it's not working for some reason.

Please help, Thank you...

Comment: Hi there, how's it not working at present?  Are you recieving any error messages?

Comment: why dont you put the above code inside a stored proc and call it from your page. using stored proc will result in slight increase of the performance too.

Comment: Please show your VBScript code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For classic ASP, you might want to check out **http://www.w3schools.com/asp/**

ADODB.Command object is the equivalent to SqlCommand. 
From there it is basically doing the same as in .NET.

```
set cmd = Server.CreateOject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.CommandText = "select From Table where ID = @id")
set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@id", adInteger, adInput,0,0)
```

See: [How do I run a parameterized SQL query in classic ASP? And is it secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579687/how-do-i-run-a-parameterized-sql-query-in-classic-asp-and-is-it-secure)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200190

Comment: I believe you meant CreateO**b**ject and not CreateOject